# How do I compare two arrays with the same value and store that same value in a new array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I tried something like:

```
var diff = $(array1).not(array2).get();
console.log(diff); // store the difference
```

And replace `.not()` with `.is()` but that didn't work..which generated an error. It only stored the difference, but I want only the same values stored in a new array. How do I do that in jQuery regardless if it's length size in both arrays?

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
var array2 = ['c', 'b'];
var sameValArr = [];

// TODO:
// 1. compare the two arrays if there's any matching values in both
// 2. if yes, store the matching value in a new array; if no, do nothing
// 3. check the new array if it isn't empty 
// 4. if empty, hide the video; if not empty do nothing (show video)

    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
        {
            if(array1.indexOf([i]) === array2.indexOf([j]))
            {
               sameValArr.push(array1[i]);
                console.log("sameValArr: ", sameValArr);
            }      
        }
    }
```

The answer provided to this question using `indexOf()` method didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried .contains() or .indexOf()?

Comment: Really not clear what the arrays have to do with `$('.class')`

Comment: @charlietfl They don't actually, I removed and updated the post, sorry about that.

Comment: @mhodges Yes, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i< array1.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j< array2.length; j++)
    {
        if(array1[i] === array2[j])
            sameValArr.push(array1[i]);
    }
{
```

Comment: This doesn't account for if the values are attached to different key locations/positions. IndexOf actually searches through and checks if its in the array at all.

Comment: Tried your answer along with indexOf() but didn't work.

Comment: My solution give you an array of the values that are presents in the 2 arrays. 
What would you do after ?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!